# Nginx configure error: can not detect int size

Tags: nginx, configure

when I try to run the "configure" command in nginx src path,the error followed comes out.

```
checking for OS
+ Linux 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... found
+ using GNU C compiler
+ gcc version: 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) 
checking for gcc -pipe switch ... found
checking for gcc builtin atomic operations ... not found
checking for C99 variadic macros ... not found
checking for gcc variadic macros ... not found
checking for unistd.h ... found
checking for inttypes.h ... found
checking for limits.h ... found
checking for sys/filio.h ... not found
checking for sys/param.h ... found
checking for sys/mount.h ... found
checking for sys/statvfs.h ... found
checking for crypt.h ... found
checking for Linux specific features
checking for epoll ... not found
checking for sendfile() ... not found
checking for sendfile64() ... not found
checking for sys/prctl.h ... found
checking for prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE) ... not found
checking for sched_setaffinity() ... not found
checking for crypt_r() ... not found
checking for sys/vfs.h ... found
checking for poll() ... not found
checking for /dev/poll ... not found
checking for kqueue ... not found
checking for crypt() ... not found
checking for crypt() in libcrypt ... not found
checking for F_READAHEAD ... not found
checking for posix_fadvise() ... not found
checking for O_DIRECT ... not found
checking for F_NOCACHE ... not found
checking for directio() ... not found
checking for statfs() ... not found
checking for statvfs() ... not found
checking for dlopen() ... not found
checking for dlopen() in libdl ... not found
checking for sched_yield() ... not found
checking for sched_yield() in librt ... not found
checking for SO_SETFIB ... not found
checking for SO_ACCEPTFILTER ... not found
checking for TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT ... not found
checking for TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPINTVL, TCP_KEEPCNT ... not found
checking for TCP_INFO ... not found
checking for accept4() ... not found
checking for int size ...
./configure: error: can not detect int size
```

My os is centos 6.0,and it already has the kernel-headers package:
  kernel-headers-2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64
the os version is:
  CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested nginx default installation without any params except the --prefix for a path. And it works, nginx was installed fluently.
And I checked the params,found that "--with-cc-opt='-m32 -march=i386'",my os is 64bit,so I delete it,and run the command.
It works as usual....

Comment: I had somewhat similar reason. One of the CFLAGS was causing the problem. Cleaned CLAGS by doing 'export CFLAGS=""' and it was resolved.

Comment: For installing on Solaris 11, setting `export CFLAGS=""` solved it for me. Thanks.

Comment: So basically you remove the whole `with-cc-opt` param?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this error a couple times before. Hopefully my two problems will help you narrow yours:

1) I mistakenly tried to compile nginx using C++ when actually it needed C.

2) I was using an incompatible plugin. The TCP proxy plugin I was using was incompatible with the most recent version of nginx. The problem was that the internals changed beyond the plugin's support.

Happy hunting.

Answer (score 0):

If on OS X, like I was, try following along this [bug report](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/94).

Basically do:

```
brew install pcre
```

and add this to your ./configure

```
--with-ld-opt="-L /usr/local/lib"
```

Comment: I'm trying to compile this with android ndk and I still have the same issue after adding the option in the configure file